# Why were these "Not an answer" flags on posts referring to other SO posts declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

## Exhibit 1:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4788059/2235132

```
Had a similar question before, this post answered it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813853/ifdef-ifndef-in-java
```

---

## Exhibit 2:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9034371/2235132

> Please see previous and similar question which was answered here:
>
> [Railsinstaller
> error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034191/railsinstaller-error/8043875#8043875)

---

The "Not an Answer" flags on these posts were **declined**:

> *declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*.

Ignoring the fact that both of these questions are duplicates, the answers are merely links pointing to other posts on the site.

Is the "Not an Answer" flag not appropriate in such cases?  Or am I being wrong in thinking that there is something wrong with the answers?

Enlighten please.

Comment: I occasionally flag answers that simply point to other SO questions/answers as NAA, and if I'm not mistaken, so far none of them have been declined.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I clearly got the wrong end of several sticks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Every link-only answer is. What's your point?

Comment: @bjb: nah, comment gone. Without the markup they are useless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I'm not always a fan of deleting link-based answers, this is a special case, and I think you were right to flag those. If the answer consists only of a link to another question on Stack Overflow, I almost always convert those to a comment.

If the answer was accepted, as it was in these cases, that's almost always an indication that the question is a duplicate of the target question. The asker themselves indicated that the solution there solved their problem.

However, one thing to note about the "not an answer" flag is that these feed into the Very Low Quality review queue. The only actions people can take there are to vote on the posts or vote to delete them. Upvoted posts cannot be deleted from that queue, so flagging upvoted or accepted answers like these will eventually kick them into the moderator review queue without any context. That might not always lead to the review outcome you desire.

Only a moderator can convert these answers into comments and/or one-click close the questions as duplicates, so if that's what you want you'll need to use an "other" flag to describe this and why you feel that would be appropriate. I'd just ask that you not go on a flagging spree of older questions and answers at the moment, because we have enough to deal with right now.

Comment: Thanks.  Don't worry, I won't go on a flagging spree digging such posts :)