# Not an answer flag declined, the answer is basically saying "it's a duplicate"

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer

I'm wondering if this answer is really a valid answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355804/generating-html-page-in-javascript-jquery-on-fly/25355980#25355980

To me this answer looks like the user just wanted to say that the question was already asked and answered. So the answerer should have instead of posting an answer should have flagged the question as duplicate. Currently the answer looks to me like a "link only answer".

I flagged the answer as "not an answer" and voted to close the question as a duplicate. But my flag got declined. Am I wrong?

How should I've handled this correctly? It can't be okay that a user gets reputation for giving an answer that's nothing more than a link to the duplicated question. If that was okay people would start to post links on duplicate questions and hope their answers get accepted.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I know about this question. But how should I've handled this correctly? It can't be okay that a user gets reputation for giving an answer that's nothing more than a link to the duplicated question. If it is okay, why not all people post links on duplicate questions and hope their answers get accepted?

Comment: It is important to downvote the answer to indicate it's lower quality. This will also open the door for removal if the question gets closed.

Comment: - Downvote the answer.  - Flag the answer as low quality.  - Vote to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: Also a comment helps to explain why it is VLQ. Now, the persons in the review queue have to guess why it isn't an answer to you.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef Thanks for your comment. Apparently the only mistake I made was to choose the wrong flag. Maybe you want to post this as an answer.

Comment: @wumm I found another post which seems to contain the same point that you're talking about.  Here it is: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266534/why-were-these-not-an-answer-flags-on-posts-referring-to-other-so-posts-declin  (I suppose that your question might be a duplicate.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't agree on the decline of your flag, but I understand why. (Okay, after some clarification from Bill the Lizard that the use of NAA is wrong, I do, a little)

It seems to be a legit answer, with a useful link and some extra comments hanging around. If you look closer, it's just a shadow copy of the original answer referred in the answer.

To prevent the reviewers to overlook the actual issue, I suggest to downvote and comment. Explain what is wrong with the post (address to the one answering, not to the reviewers). Flag after some time without a response from the poster.

Answer (score -1):

It was declined because it's a genuine (albeit poor) attempt to answer the question - so it *is* an answer. The author of that answer *should* have simply flagged it as a duplicate and moved on.

Comment: A link to another question is not an answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, you're right it isn't. But "Simply change the download attribute on the 'a' element to have an extension of html." is. Whether it's relevant or correct isn't taken into account when addressing "Not an Answer" flags.

Comment: Or it was just a repetition of the linked answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Doesn't matter - it *looks like it could be an answer*. That's all that's taken into consideration when resolving that particular flag. It's not for flagging as "Not an answer to this question", just for "this is not an answer to a question".

Comment: That why I suggested to comment before you flag so it is clear *why* it isn't an answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman If you need to comment on it you should probably be using a custom flag rather than an out-of-the-box flag. Not an Answer is not the appropriate flag for that answer, and it was correctly declined - and even if you did comment on it and re-flag, I would expect it to be declined again.

Comment: NAA's are usually handled by the community, so it is sometimes necessary to elaborate.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's still an answer though, so like it or not a "Not an Answer" flag **should always be declined**. VLQ or a custom flag would be appropriate, but not NAA.

Comment: JonK is right here. The "Not an Answer" flag should only be used for things that in no way attempt to answer the question. Moderators don't have time to investigate the nuance of posts like this. If it looks like an answer, we leave it. A custom flag (not VLQ) should be used in cases like this. In this particular case the question should just be closed as a duplicate, since the accepted answer just points to the original Q&A.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Why isn't the answer deleted yet? Any particular reason for it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Probably because it's an accepted answer - deleting it will also remove reputation from the asker. Granted it's not a significant amount in the grand scheme of things, but could be seen as also penalising the asker.

Comment: @JonK: True, but mods and 20K users can (vote to) delete, so there is a possibility and a reason for it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman There's no reason to take action one way or the other on the answer. The question just needed to be closed as duplicate. (I did delete the answer though, since I was there.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Thanks. In my opinion, such answers should be deleted since they are just a link with irrelevant data from the linked post.